# Turtle Onkey - Enter Key

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Simple question, what is the term for the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key for `Turtle.Onkey()`

I've tried `turtle.onkey(check, 'Enter')` but I get the error:

```
TclError: bad event type or keysym "Enter"
```

So, I think that I have entered the wrong word for 'Enter'

Just in-case you don't know what the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, here it is :P

[image: The Enter Key]

Comment: have you tried `'return'`?

Answer (score 4):

Use `'Return'`
For example, `turtle.onkey(check, 'Return')`.

Answer (score -1):

```
turtle.onkey(check, 'return')
```

This should do it.

Comment: This generates a `bad event type or keysym "return"` error, needs to be `'Return'`.